# React Native - mocking FormData in unit tests

Tags: unit-testing, react-native, fetch-api, jestjs

I'm having issues testing my thunks, as many of my API calls are using FormData, and I can't seem to figure out how to mock this in tests. I'm using Jest.

My setup file looks like this:

```js
import 'isomorphic-fetch';

// Mocking the global.fetch included in React Native
global.fetch = jest.fn();

// Helper to mock a success response (only once)
fetch.mockResponseSuccess = body => {
  fetch.mockImplementationOnce(() =>
    Promise.resolve({ json: () => Promise.resolve(JSON.parse(body)) })
  );
};

// Helper to mock a failure response (only once)
fetch.mockResponseFailure = error => {
  fetch.mockImplementationOnce(() => Promise.reject(error));
};
```

However, I get the following error on all tests that require FormData:

```
ReferenceError: FormData is not defined
```

I've tried importing the FormData file from `react-native-mock`, under `src/Libraries/Network/FormData`, but it didn't work.

So I was wondering if anyone has had any luck doing this?

In general, I'm having a hard time figuring out the best way to mock `fetch` requests in React Native, so any advice here would be nice. I've tried the `jest-fetch-mock` lib (and opened an issue about FormData), tried setting up with `nock` (no luck), and this plain Jest implementation, but nothing feels right yet.

Comment: Did you find a solution that worked for you?

Comment: Not yet, unfortunately

Answer (score 22):

This is an old question, but since I've found it in first page at google, here goes what I've done:

at the beginning of my test I added:

```
function FormDataMock() {
    this.append = jest.fn();
}
global.FormData = FormDataMock
```

this will make sure all places that do

```
const formData = new FormData()
```

will use my mock.

Of course, I've only mocked the 'append' method, since in my case it was the only thing I needed. The function that I was testing returned the created FormData object and I did this to test if all worked as expected:

```
const resultFormData = theFunction()
expect(resultFormData.append.mock.calls.sort(sortFunc)).toEqual(expected)
```

Comment: Are you able to use this solution with an installed external library that uses `FormData.append`? I've tried adding the `FormDataMock` code above to `beforeEach` in my simple test, however, I still get `FormData is not defined` from a library used within my project. Thanks.

Comment: I tested this only with local code, not with external libraries. What is the library you tried to test?

Comment: The library is [react-native-aws3](https://github.com/benjreinhart/react-native-aws3), though I actually don't want to test it myself. It's causing my very basic test to fail, possibly just because it's a dependency in my React Native project???

Comment: have you tried adding the `global.FormData = ...` _before_ importing any other library?

Comment: Adding `global.FormData = ...` before importing any other library did **not** work for me. What did end up working was: `jest.mock('react-native-aws3', () => {  return { Request: { FormData: {} } } });`. I'm not sure if this is the right thing to do as it appears I'll have to do it for a number of my dependencies.

Answer (score 5):

this seems working in my case:

```
// @ts-ignore
global.FormData = require('react-native/Libraries/Network/FormData');
```

Answer (score 2):

Add the following code to beginning of your test file

```
global.FormData = require('FormData')
```

or

have something like this in your package.json

```
{
    "jest": {
        "preset": "react-native",
        "transformIgnorePatterns": [
          "<rootDir>/node_modules/(?!react-native|tcomb-form-native|ReactUtils|react-native-button)"
        ],
        "automock": false,
        "setupFiles": [
          "./setupJest.js"
        ]
      }
}
```

Then create a `setupJest.js` file on same folder as `package.json` and have following code in it

```
global.FormData = require('FormData')
```

So that `jest` calls the `setupJest.js` every time `jest` runs test

Comment: the problem being that FormData (from npm) isn't the same implementation than the one in react-native. There's a "getAll" missing.