# How to use jest to test an endpoint that expects formData and uses multer?

Tags: node.js, typescript, jestjs, multer, form-data

I have TypeScript setup and I am testing an endpoint that takes `FormData` as an input and uses `multer` to process the multipart data (pdf file); it looks like this:

```
app.post("/v1/sources/send-email", 
  upload.single('file'),
  handledEmail
);
```

My jest test has a post request that passes dummy `formData` to it in the `send` method, it looks like this:

```
import FormData from 'form-data';
    ...
    const response = await request(app)
      .post("/v1/sources/send-email")
      .send(formData)
      .set("X-AUTH-TOKEN", validToken);
```

However, when I try to create `formData` like the following, I get an error:

```
let formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', fs.createReadStream('path/to/file.pdf'));
```

The error is:

```
Argument of type 'ReadStream' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | Blob'.
```

Any ideas on how I can get this PDF file on this formData variable, so I can pass it to the test's post request?

My `tsconfig.json` looks like the following:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": false,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "lib": ["DOM", "ES2018"],
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "paths": {
      "*": [
        "src/main/ts/*",
        "node_modules/*"
      ]
    },
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es6"
  },
  "include": ["src/main/ts/**/*"]
}
```

I saw someone [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45842088/react-native-mocking-formdata-in-unit-tests) say that creating a function to mock `FormData` might work, but when I do the following, there is an error in the `global` assignment:

```
function FormDataMock() {
  this.append = jest.fn();
}
global.FormData = FormDataMock();
```

The error says `Property 'FormData' does not exist on type 'Global'.`

Comment: Is this is a typescript compilation error you're getting? Can you share your TS config and the type definitions you're using, if any?

Comment: @shkaper yes, this is a TS setup and I think my main issue is how to mock the expected `FormData`, so I can pass it in the `send` command to the `post` request.